# Stuck On Understanding a Binomial Coefficients Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

While reading a proof on the nature of binomial coefficients, the author of the text makes a leap I can't understand. Namely, he states that if $k \lt \frac{n+1}{2}$, such that $k$ is an integer, and $n$ is even; then the equation is equivalent to $k \le \frac{n}{2}$. I don't fully understand how this is justified. I tried working the reasoning out on my own. What I reasoned is as follows: since $k$ is an integer, if we add $1$ to the RHS of the equation we should have $k + 1 \le \frac{n + 1}{2}$. From here, $k \le \frac{n – 1}{2}$. I don't know what else I could add.

Another related thing he does is that he states that, if $n$ is odd, and $k$ is, again, an integer, then $k \lt \frac{n + 1}{2}$ is equivalent to $k \le \frac{n – 1}{2}$. Again, I am only further puzzled. Help would be of use. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that those inequalities have nothing to do with binomial coefficients, so if that relationship is confusing you, forget about that for now. Just focus on them as integers. $\quad$ IE In the first case, if $n = 2 m$, how can we proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is even then $n+1$ is odd and since $2$ doesn't divide an odd number we get that $\frac{n+1}{2}=m+\frac{1}{2}$ for $m=\frac{n}{2}\in\mathbb Z$.

But we know that $k$ is an integer so it has no fractional part. Therefore, $k\lt\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\implies k\le\frac{n}{2}$.

The related problems are solved similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n=2m$ where $m$ is an integer. One has

$$k\lt {2m+1\over 2}=m+{1\over 2}$$

But $k$ is an integer therefore

$$k\leq m={n\over 2}$$

Now assume $n=2m+1$ where $m$ is an integer. One has

$$k\lt {2m+2\over 2}=m+1$$

$k$ being an integer we have

$$k\leq m={n-1\over 2}$$